# How to validate request json in Lumen

Tags: php, lumen

how to valdate request json in lumen ?
i have request json like this :

```
{ 
    account : {"id" : "1", "username" : "dummy1", "password":"1234"},
    information : {"realName":"Dummy 1", "age" : 20, "bod":"dd-mm-yyyy"}
}
```

and i tried like this in my controllers :

```
$formData = $request->json()->all();
$data = array_merge($formData['user'], $formData['profile']);
$validator = $this->validate($data, [
    "id" => "required",
    "username" => "required",
    "realName" => "required",
    // etc rules
]);
```

but i always got an error like this :

> Argument 1 passed to Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given,

pls help to solving my problem,
any help will be appreciated

thanks

Comment: $data  is an array, it is not a $request